# How to trigger event resizing in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

fullCalendar have eventResizeStart, eventResizeStop and eventResize  events.

But I can't found a eventResizing event.

How I can trigger (manually) an event on every change when user are resizing an item of calendar?

I need to update dynamically the content of event meanwhile is being resized, something like:

```
+----------------+
| Event Title    |
| From: {from}   |
| To: {to}       |
+----------------+
```

I need to update `{from}` and `{to}` when mouse moves in resize operation.

Comment: It's not clear why you would need any other event? If the user is resizing an event, then the callbacks you've listed above will be executed. So you can use those to take whatever action you need to.

Comment: @ADyson I updated my question with more info about what I need, thanks.

Comment: See the demo on the [FullCalendar home page](https://fullcalendar.io/). Go to the "week" view. Drag any event or resize it - you'll see the time change as you go. This is built-in by default.